# What happens with child context when reseting it, meanwhile parent was updated?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

If I create a parent / child context like below and recommended [by CoreData guru Marcus Zarra](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/):

```
// create writer MOC
_privateWriterContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[_privateWriterContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:_persistentStoreCoordinator];

// create main thread MOC
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
_managedObjectContext.parentContext = _privateWriterContext;
```

and for certain reason I am adding changes to `_managedObjectContext` and `_privateWriterContext` too, and `save` only `_privateWriterContext`, and latter on I `reset` `_managedObjectContext`, then `_managedObjectContext` will reset to `_privateWriterContext` updated state?

`rollback` would have the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a situation as above that you have a private queue context which is attached to persistent store. Now, you create a child context from it, insert some object to this child context. When you save the child context and propagate the changes to the parent context to save it, the changes are already saved to persistent store.

Now, at this time resetting means simply nothing, it just clears the managed object contexts cache. So, if you reset the child context, then the cache that it has will be cleared. That also means that, if you do the fetch on this child context again, all those changes that were saved, will show again.  If your purpose is to undo the changes in managedObjectContext, **NSManagedObjectContext** class provides **undo**, **rollback** methods that you can use.

Resetting simply means nothing. Every managed object has its own cache, which keeps track of all the fetched object in its memory, so if you reset a managedObjectContext, all the objects from its memory gets cleared.

Comment: you are right, of course,  fine-tuned my question, I want to save only `_privateWriterContext`

Comment: What do you want to do with the child context changes then ?

Comment: `_managedObjectContext` is just for GUI, it is an in memory cache, I do not care if changes are loosing, the purpose is sometimes user interaction coming too quickly, and I want to keep `_managedObjectContext` in sync with these interactions

Comment: Ok, so you simply want to it be used as a cache. Infact it works quite nicely. Unless you propagate the save message to parent context, the object are not saved and any time you reset or when your managedObjectContext gets deallocated all objects are released as well.

Comment: Let me know if it does not.